# MySQL error in a procedure #1351 - View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mamp

PhpMyAdmin doesn't accept the parameters "id_jugador_IN" inside the procedure.

This is the procedure we're executing:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;

use traviandatabase;

DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_monitoritzacio_jugador $$

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_monitoritzacio_jugador(IN id_jugador_IN INT(10))

BEGIN

    CREATE OR REPLACE 
    VIEW dades_ususari AS 
    SELECT j.nom AS jugador, j.sexe AS sexe, j.edat AS edat, j.correu AS correu, a.nom AS alianca, p.nom AS pais, c.nom_ciutat AS ciutat
    FROM jugador AS j
    JOIN alianca AS a
    JOIN pais AS p
    JOIN ciutat AS c
    ON j.id_jugador = id_jugador_IN
    GROUP BY id_jugador_IN;

END $$

DELIMITER ;

CALL sp_monitoritzacio_jugador(1);
```

And this is the table "jugador":

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `jugador`;
CREATE TABLE `jugador` (
  `id_jugador` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_raca` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `id_pais` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `id_alianca` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
  `nom` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `sexe` enum('Home','Dona') NOT NULL,
  `edat` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `correu` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_jugador`),
  KEY `jugador-alianca` (`id_alianca`),
  KEY `id_pais` (`id_pais`),
  KEY `id_raca` (`id_raca`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

So it doesn't stop displaying the same error:

MySQL said: 1351 - View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you see - view cannot use variables, it is a limitation. You are trying to create a view with exact WHERE condition; construct the CREATE VIEW statement text firstly, then use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to execute the statement, it will help you. But, do you really need it, to create, create and create new view?

EDIT: This is the content of the reference in the comment.

[Olexandr Melnyk](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html#c8695) A simple workaround for MySQL's limitation on local variables usage in views is to use a function, which returns variable's value:

```
create function book_subject
returns varchar(64) as
return @book_subject;

create view thematical_books as
select title
, author
from books
where subject = book_subject();
```

Comment: Yes I need it because its a requirement for an exercise.. I know, it sucks. Thank you for the information!

Comment: Have a look at views's documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html. There are user comments, read  this one - 'A simple workaround for MySQL's limitation on local variables usage in views...' It might help you.

Comment: In my installation, this workaround has the side effect that the view `thematical_books` does not use the index on `subject` in `books`.