# Create auto increment id in view mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have table with two columns Product1, Product2. I cant modify this table but i need id. So i want to create view with Id column.

```
    CREATE 
        ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
        DEFINER = `schaefers`@`%` 
        SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    VIEW `products_view` AS
     SELECT @i:=@i+1 AS iterator, t.*
      FROM Products,(SELECT @i:=0) foo;
```

After that i get this:  ERROR 1351: View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292258/mysql-error-in-a-procedure-1351-views-select-contains-a-variable-or-paramete

Comment: I try to do similary but dont have any idea how store incremented value in funtion

Comment: I did this 
CREATE DEFINER=`ss`@`%` FUNCTION `products_fun`() RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
declare  i INT;
SET i = i+1;
RETURN i;
END